# Move a label every time you click a button PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to move the ligne of labels to the left by adding to their coordinate 100 every time I push a specific button.

I tied to call the show tab function inside the move_ligne_one() function but I cant refer to it

```
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Simple window'
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 1100
        self.height = 800
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("img/icon.png"))

        def show_tab(left_cord):
            ligne_1_left_cord = left_cord
            label_ligne_1_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            #pic_signe_x =QPixmap('img/x.png')
            #label_ligne_1_1.setPixmap(pic_signe_x)
            label_ligne_1_1.setText("X")
            label_ligne_1_1.move(ligne_1_left_cord,300)

            label_ligne_1_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            #pic_signe_x =QPixmap('img/x.png')
            #label_ligne_1_1.setPixmap(pic_signe_x)
            label_ligne_1_2.setText("X")
            label_ligne_1_2.move( ligne_1_left_cord +200,300)


            label_ligne_1_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            #pic_signe_x =QPixmap('img/x.png')
            #label_ligne_1_1.setPixmap(pic_signe_x)
            label_ligne_1_3.setText("X")
            label_ligne_1_3.move( ligne_1_left_cord +400,300)


            label_ligne_1_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            #pic_signe_x =QPixmap('img/x.png')
            #label_ligne_1_1.setPixmap(pic_signe_x)
            label_ligne_1_4.setText("X")
            label_ligne_1_4.move( ligne_1_left_cord +600,300)

        buttonStart = QPushButton('START', self)
        buttonStart.setGeometry(380, 700, 250, 61)
        buttonStart.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        button_left_1 = QPushButton('<', self)
        button_left_1.setGeometry(45,300,30,30)
        button_left_1.clicked.connect(self.move_ligne_one)


        show_tab(275)
        self.show()


    @pyqtSlot()
    def move_ligne_one(self):
        print(' button click')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to move a widget then the first thing is to access that widget so you have to do it class attribute:

```
# ...
self.label_ligne_1_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
# ...
self.label_ligne_1_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
# ...
self.label_ligne_1_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
# ...
self.label_ligne_1_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
# ...
```

And then modify the position:

```py
@pyqtSlot()
def move_ligne_one(self):
    for btn in (
        self.label_ligne_1_1,
        self.label_ligne_1_2,
        self.label_ligne_1_3,
        self.label_ligne_1_4,
    ):
        p = btn.pos()
        p += QtCore.QPoint(100, 0)
        btn.move(p)
```